# APPHOST9623 error when develop UWP application with winJS

Tags: win-universal-app, winjs

I just copy the code in [microsoft hello world examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt280216.aspx#), but when I ran this examples, it gave out the error(Sorry to show the error with some Chinese^_^):

```
APPHOST9623: 由于此错误，应用无法解析 ms-appx://9d394822-bc2e-4927-b83e-4a53bd570833/lib/winjs-4.0.1/fonts/Symbols.ttf: DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE。
CSS3117: @font-face 跨源请求失败。资源访问受限。
Symbols.ttf
CSS3120: 无可用于 @font-face 规则的字体
ui-light.css (361,7)
APPHOST9623: 由于此错误，应用无法解析 ms-appx://9d394822-bc2e-4927-b83e-4a53bd570833/lib/winjs-4.0.1/fonts/Symbols.ttf: DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE。
CSS3117: @font-face 跨源请求失败。资源访问受限。
Symbols.ttf
CSS3120: 无可用于 @font-face 规则的字体
ui-light.css (361,7)
APPHOST9623: 由于此错误，应用无法解析 ms-appx://9d394822-bc2e-4927-b83e-4a53bd570833/lib/winjs-4.0.1/fonts/Symbols.ttf: DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE。
CSS3117: @font-face 跨源请求失败。资源访问受限。
Symbols.ttf
CSS3120: 无可用于 @font-face 规则的字体
ui-light.css (361,7)
```

I didn't modify any code of the examples, how can I fix this error?

Comment: The font file under your project seems damaged or removed. Please check the "Symbols.ttf" file under "WinJS\fonts\Sybols.ttf". If it is removed, recreate a project and copy the new font file to your current project.

Comment: @ElvisXia I have added it to my project. But the error still exists. And when I run the code first time, it doesn't give any error.

Comment: @ElvisXia After I restart the IDE, the error is fixed, thank you!